# R script in background forever

Tags: r, sockets, rscript

My Tcl program is communicating with R through sockets. To do so, I launch R in terminal 1 in INTERACTIVE MODE :

```
library(svSocket)
startSocketServer(local=TRUE, secure=FALSE)
```

My Tcl program is running in terminal 2.

I'd like to make the socket server running in the background. I created the following script in file server.R :

```
library(svSocket)
startSocketServer(local=TRUE, secure=FALSE)
while (1) {}
```

If I run on Ubuntu :

```
$ Rscript server.R &
```

the script finishes and never stays in the process list although the infinite 'while' loop.

Can someone tell me why this script ends ?

How can I make this script to stay alive in the background forever ?

Many thanks in advance !
Luc

Comment: As you are on Ubuntu:  look into the [Rserve](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/r-cran-rserve) package.  It has a matching client too.  You may be able to bend you Tcl app to use it. Deployment should be stabler that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup CMD BATCH server.R &
```

---

tmux/screen,
eg. tmux (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux)
1. enter tmux envirioment

```
tmux -S serverR #create a session named serverR
```

run your r script, eg.
    Rscript server.R &